# Ensuring that all points are on the convex hull of a triangulation

Tags: c++, triangulation, cgal, convex-hull, delaunay

I currently have a program that takes in a set of points, triangulates it using CGAL, and then extracts the convex hull of these points. However, I was wondering, instead of finding the convex hull of the points, how can I create a triangulation such that all points are on the convex hull of the triangulation? I don't want any code, but was wondering how I would go about implementing this in CGAL. Please let me know if you need any more clarification, and any help would be awesome!

Comment: " how can I create a triangulation such that all points are on the convex hull of the triangulation? " sounds like 'how to get a convex hull' (without triangulation) and triangulate that hull (which should be trivial).

Answer (score 0):

Cgal uses incremental algorithm. Maybe you can check when a point shares more then 2 vertices in the triangulation and if so mark it as visited and delete all newly formed triangles.